# Delete delta table in Databricks with R

Tags: r, databricks, delta-lake, sparklyr

I'm trying to delete a delta table using **R** from Databricks.

It works if I do :

```
system("rm -rf /my_dir/my_table")
```

But I don't really like this solution...

Is there a more elegant solution in **R** ?

### **Solution**

```
dbutils.fs.rm("/my_dir/my_table")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about using [dbutils](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-fs-rm)? like,

```r
dbutils.fs.rm("....path...", recurse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Because I would like the command to be inside R code. For example : if(condition) delete("/my_dir/my_table")

Comment: it works perfectly inside R code

Comment: You're write. I thought it worked only with Scala. Thanks !